# SDL_renderer becomes null when creating

Tags: c++, null, sdl, sdl-2, renderer

I have this annoying problem that when I create an SDL_renderer in one of my classes it becomes a nullptr but when creating another one in another class it functions normally.

Creating a renderer in my Engine class, functions normally:

```
m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Breakout", 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
    m_window_width, m_window_height, 
    SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, 
    SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```

Creating a renderer in my DrawManager class, renderer becomes a nullptr:

```
bool DrawManager::Initialize(SDL_Window *window, int width, int height) {
    m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    if(m_renderer == nullptr) {
        return false;
    };

    return true;

};
```

The m_renderer variables are created in each class respective header file.

The window that is created in the Engine class is sent into the DrawManager's Initialize method and the window is not a nullptr, only the renderer is. Both classes have the same SDL related includes.

Anyone has any ideas what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You want to draw with OpenGL?

If so, you don't need renderer. Otherwise, if you want to use simple SDL draw functions, try to remove `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag from `SDL_CreateWindow()`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ended up with sending the original renderer instead, since I'm not that familiar with SDL and on kind of a tight schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `SDL_CreateRenderer` twice? If so, try calling it only once and passing the pointer around.